# DAX - Join multiple strings and ignore null or empty values

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to join multiple string values into a single string using DAX. I get the strings from several columns of a table.

Examples

"I", "", "" -> "I"

"", "got", "" -> "got"

"I", "got", "" -> "I, got"

"I", "", "rhythm" -> "I, rhythm"

The best I came up with is COMBINEVALUES(", ", string1, string2, string3 ...)
but this does not ignore null or empty value. The output of the first example would be

"I, , "

The function has nothing similar to the ignore_empty parameter in Excel TEXTJOIN. 
Is there a simple way to achieve it?

Comment: How do you like the output if string1 empty and string2 has text? Or if both string1 and string2 is empty?

Comment: commas only between non-empty strings.

Comment: See edit on my previous answer.

Comment: Now i fixed it so it handles three columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Data = "TEST"
Index   string1 string2 string3
0       I       null    null
1       null    got     null
2       I       null    rhythm
3       null    null    null

CONCAT = 
VAR STRING1 = MAX(TEST[string1])
VAR STRING2 = MAX(TEST[string2])
VAR STRING3 = MAX(TEST[string3])

RETURN
Switch(True();
        LEN(STRING1) > 0 && LEN(STRING2) > 0 && LEN(STRING3) > 0; STRING1 & ", " & STRING2 & ", " & STRING3;
        LEN(STRING1) > 0 && LEN(STRING2) > 0 && LEN(STRING3) = 0; STRING1 & ", " & STRING2;
        LEN(STRING1) > 0 && LEN(STRING2) = 0 && LEN(STRING3) > 0; STRING1 & ", " & STRING3;
        LEN(STRING1) = 0 && LEN(STRING2) > 0 && LEN(STRING3) > 0; STRING2 & ", " & STRING3;
        LEN(STRING1) > 0 && LEN(STRING2) = 0 && LEN(STRING3) = 0; STRING1;
        LEN(STRING1) = 0 && LEN(STRING2) > 0 && LEN(STRING3) = 0; STRING2;
        LEN(STRING1) = 0 && LEN(STRING2) = 0 && LEN(STRING3) > 0; STRING3;
        LEN(STRING1) = 0 && LEN(STRING2) = 0 && LEN(STRING3) = 0; BLANK())
```

Output when MATRIX, Rows = Index, Values = CONCAT:

```
I
got   
I, rhythm
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use CONCATENATE, this is not combining values but joining text

```
CONCATENATE(<text1>, <text2>)
```

You can alos use:

```
NewColumn = text1 & text2
```

Comment: This does not address ignoring empty values

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting these values from a column, then you can filter out empty strings and used `CONCATENATEX`:

```
JoinText =
    CONCATENATEX ( 
        FILTER ( Table1, LEN ( Table1[Text] ) > 0 ),
        Table1[Text],
        ", "
    )
```

Otherwise, it would be useful to know where your strings are coming from.